# Prevent DataGrid from handling Enter-key

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a *readonly* DataGrid showing items inside a window that is shown as dialog. This dialog also has two buttons, one to confirm and one to cancel the dialog. The confirm button's `IsDefault` property is set to `true`, the cancel button's `IsCancel` property is set to `true`. I want to keep up the default dialog button behaviour, i.e. confirming and closing the dialog when pressing the confirm button or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *or* cancelling and closing it by pressing the cancel button or <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>.

Unfortunately the DataGrid consumes the `KeyDown` event of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>-key and selects the next row inside the grid. Because the `KeyDown` event is marked as handled by the DataGrid the dialog will not be confirmed and stays open. My desired behaviour is that the selected row is not changed and the dialog will be confirmed and closed.

I could create my own DataGrid-derived type an overwrite `OnKeyDown` as follows:

```cs
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is another way without having to create a derived type to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the curernt `DataGrid`.

```xml
<DataGrid PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

```cs
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // This makes this key pressed event end here.
        e.Handled = true;
        // Do what you need to do here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This prevents the change of the selected row but will not trigger the confirm button to be clicked...

Comment: Can't you do the confirm programmatically? Right after the **Do what you need to do here...** comment.

Comment: Well, not directly, because the logic of the dialog button is separated from the logic of the data grid view.

Thanks anyway, I use your solution and raise an event that is handled in the dialog logic.